# Create folder and subfolders from hrefs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying using nodejs to create folder and subfolders from anchors on a specific div.

Any idea appreciate.

Also I have to do the same for many file with different links.

I try the below code but I create the folders on the same root and not under index.

```
    $('#breadcrumb-section').each((i, ul) => {
  const children = $(ul).children();
  const selectedAnchors = $(ul).find("A");
  selectedAnchors.each((i, a) => {
    //console.log($(a).attr('href'));
    //console.log($(a).text())
    const href = $(a).attr('href');
    const file = path.parse(href).name;

    var dir = dir +"/"+ file ;
    console.log(dir)

    if (fs.existsSync(dir)){
      process.chdir(dir);
      dir = file;
      console.log(dir, "Exists")
    }
    else{
      dir += file
      console.log(dir, "does not exists");
      fs.mkdirSync(dir);
      dir = dir + "/"
      console.log(dir)
    }

      })
    });
```

When I run I get

undefined/index
undefined/Business-Intelligence-and-Data-Integration-Project_76385820
undefined/03-Analysis-and-Requirements_76385897

instead of
index/Business-Intelligence-and-Data-Integration-Project_76385820/03-Analysis-and-Requirements_76385897.

Comment: Can you post console.logs as well as your folder structure?

Comment: When I run I get

undefined/index
undefined/Business-Intelligence-and-Data-Integration-Project_76385820
undefined/03-Analysis-and-Requirements_76385897

instead of 
index/Business-Intelligence-and-Data-Integration-Project_76385820/03-Analysis-and-Requirements_76385897

Comment: You can edit your question with logs and folder structure.